# Object Export: Hidden entities of model are getting exported (they shouldn't get exported)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Hi we are trying to export a saved view from the forge viewer.

When trying to export a view with hidden entities we find that the hidden entities do not get removed from the export and the entire model gets exported as it is.

We also tried doing this in postman by only giving the dbIds of entities visible in the model. The results were same, entire model got exported instead of only the non-hidden entities.

We are doing this using the forge model derivatives API- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/

[image: Hidden entities in viewer]

[image: Model after export]

Answer (score 0):

To extract geometry in **OBJ** you can follow this : [Extract Geometry](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-geometry-from-source-file/task5-extract_geometry/)
As you can see, you can specify `dbids` you want in your extract.

After the extraction is done, check the manifest and you will get all **OBJ** files with the list of extracted `dbids` like this :

```
{
   "modelGuid": "b90bbb37-d60e-412c-aedc-bf8c049f0dc7",
   "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE/output/geometry/b576231b-9684-3609-8fa0-1221a424a77c.mtl",
   "role": "obj",
   "guid": "fed3c1b1-3c99-34d1-81f1-79f6fea72576",
   "type": "resource",
   "objectIds": [
        4,
        5
   ],
   "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: I checked the manifest but it shows the correct objectIds (with hidden dbIds removed) array, but still the entire model is getting downloaded.